# Installation Problem Error: Kernel_thread_helper

Tags: acpi

Good afternoon forumer of this great Ubuntu community, I pose my problem to see if I can help find a solution.!

My computer a P4 HT 1GB of Ram 160DD My Chipset is intel Start with the live USB and will not let me install or run the USB system from the start of due process but ends up an error: Kernel_thread_helper +0 x6/0x10

Achieve install the system with F1 then F6 and write to the boot: "live-install acpi = off and give me step and the installation wizard! Normally installed and make dual boot win7 with my other OS when trying to start ubuntu 3.0.0 charge q ubuntu linux .... so generic happens to a black screen and console or two and just get a blinking courses and more I have nothing I can be understood to be the same so I did not install at the beginning dajaba ? in recovery mode I can not access will know how I can solve the problem since I can not get into ubuntu in any way or by the installation or by the live usb!

The ubuntu installed is 11.10

I appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 1):

If you are having issues using the standard Ubuntu GUI installation method I recommend you try the alternate installer which [can be found here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download#alternate).

For your information;

> Alternate installer details
>
> The text-based alternate installer can be downloaded from a location
>   near you. This installation CD is suited for computers unable to run
>   the graphical desktop based installation, either because their
>   computer does not meet the minimum requirements for the live cd or
>   because their computer requires configuration after the installation
>   is complete in order to use the desktop.